# Testing for Dropdown Value

Tags: templating

I've set up a dropdown field for the client to choose from a list of pre-defined addresses.  In my template, I want to determine whether the field has a value or not.  When I look in the database, Entry A has a value of 'NULL', while Entry B has a value of 'address1'.  So the field is working properly in those regards.

However, in my template it's all or nothing.  Here is my code:

```
{% if event.includeMap|length %}
<tr>
    <th class="small">
        Defined? {{ event.includeMap is defined }}<br>
        Not Null? {{ event.includeMap is not null }}<br>
        Null: {{ event.includeMap is null }}<br>
        Value: {{ event.includeMap }}
    </th>
    <td align="center">
        {% include 'partials/_inc-map' %}
    </td>
</tr>
{% endif %}
```

I've added the options in the left column to see what the database returns.  In both cases, they return the same values.  However, with Entry A, nothing is returned as a value, and in Entry B, the correct value appears.

I have also tried

```
{% if event.includeMap is defined %}
{% if event.includeMap is not null %}
```

Any other thoughts?

Comment: How does your dropdown not have anything selected?  Do you have an empty label/value at the top or something and you consider that nothing selected?

Comment: I have the first option as a "Please Select...." with nothing as a value (which someone recommended in another post).  Am I better off adding a value of 0 or something and testing against that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you've got a dropdown field defined with no value as one of the options, it should be as simple as:

```
{% if entry.dropdownFieldHandle %}
    {{ entry.dropdownFieldHandle }}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Thanks Brad.  I'm going to mark this as the correct answer because it does work.  However, it is showing content inside the {% if %} statement even if a value has been selected from the dropdown, which is strange.  No worries though, I am modifying my template to avoid that.